# Android Studio doesn't recognize 9patch generated images

Tags: android, android-studio, nine-patch

I generated 9patch images from Simple 9 patch generator available free on the internet for the splash screen. When I write `android:background="@drawable/splash.9"`, it doesn't recognize the image.

Plus , when I select `Android` from the drop down menu on left top side , I don't see the images I put in different drawable folders.
[image]
[image]

Comment: did u get any solution? still it is not working in my Android Studio.

Comment: Answer by @Mannaz worked for me

Comment: http://prntscr.com/brit1m can u pls check mine error..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to add the `.9` suffix. It's just there to tell the build environment that this is a 9patch. [Link to documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch).

```
android:background="@drawable/splash"
```

should be enough

Comment: but I still get the error that `Cannot resolve symbol @drawable/splash`

Comment: try rebuilding the project and check if your file is a valid 9patch

Comment: @Mannaz it is not working for me.  
can u pls check mine error.. 
http://image.prntscr.com/image/017dc7c9a871447988583ef8dd7abf12.png

Comment: @HimanshuMori the error description is right there in your screenshot. Your file is not a valid 9patch file. Please check the specification and make sure your file has the 1px transparent border.

Comment: yeah very strange. it was working fine in Eclipse.. issue came to me after migrating same project to Android studio.